# Not able to add !important to fontWeight property in typescript css classes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I wanted to add **!important** to *fontWeight* property in typescript css classes.

As fontWeight required value to be in numeric, while appending !important I have tried it using a string like '300 !important' but this is giving me a type error.

So, tried adding fontWeight: '300 !important' as any, but somewhere it is working fine but somewhere it is giving an compilation error. Not able to figure out why it is so.

Thanks in advance.

[image]